# How to build .deb package that adds a GUI program to session startup?

Tags: startup, upstart, packaging

I have a built .deb installer that installs the GUI<sup>(1)</sup> program `myprog`.

I would like this .deb installer to add `myprog` to the *Session Startup* programs for **all** the users on the system.

- Should this be done by adding an upstart job to `/etc/init/`? What should the job start on?
- Do we have an example of a package in the Ubuntu repository that does this?

*1. `myprog` is an application indicator*

Comment: do you want one instance of `myprog` to be running or one per user running in each user context?

Comment: can you show your steps to do this *not* as part of a package?

Comment: @Skaperen the application is not user specific so I would have run it once for the system. But I suppose it would not be a problem running it once per user context.

Comment: @Skaperen I would do it by adding a `.desktop` entry to `~/.config/autostart`for all users that can login. This is not a very good solution as it  will need to be run each time a new user is created.

Comment: Hi @danjjl see my answer, I tested it. please leave a comment if It needs more explanation., or you need any help on the script or the different `.desktop` files. (autostart script/autostart application).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Autostart an application for all users

To autostart an application, either which user logs is, you can store a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Automatically start up an application from a launcher in`/etc/xdg/autostart` will also:

- give individual users the opportunity to *unset* autostart. The `.desktop` file will be automatically copied from `/etc/xdg/autostart` to `~/.config/autostart` if the user disables autostart from Startup Applications. The local autostart `.desktop` file will then overrule the one in `/etc/xdg/autostart`
- have the advantage that the application autostarts by default for newly created users.

Comment: Thank you! Seems fine. Is it necessary to manually create the `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/`. With only a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`, after launching **Startup Applications** Ubuntu seems to create a copy of the `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/`. The file in the home directory then has precedence over the file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`

Comment: @danjjl you are right! That is new to me as well, as soon as you edit the startup option, the `.desktop` file is copied locally, doing the job I had in mind for the script :) I will edit my answer.